# How to make some item unselectable in Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, unselect

I have this Dialog with 4 items in it. And I need to make for example first item unselectable (unclickable), how can I do that?

```
String[] presets = { getString(R.string.string1), getString(R.string.string2), getString(R.string.string3), getString(R.string.string4) };
            AlertDialog dialog;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListFragment.this.getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(name);
            builder.setItems(presets, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position1) {
                    switch(position1) {
                    case 0:
                        //some code
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //some code
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //some code
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //some code
                        break;
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: do you mean clickable ?

Comment: Yes..................

Comment: So could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

in your xml make this for the widget you don't want it to be clickable

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: I don't have any xml, I have only this Dialog.

Comment: however I know that every widget can be set not clickable using java like this `yourWidget.setClickable(false)`;

Comment: I don't have widget, but Dialog.